# How to list all expired service principal credentials in Azure active directory

Tags: azure, entra-id, azure-cli

I recently had an issue that turned out to be caused by an expired service principal credential. I would like to have a simple way to get a list of all the expiration dates/expired sp credentials to avoid this problem in the future. I've been looking at the odata and jsonpath documentation but it keeps getting errors.
Currently I can run this command in AZ CLI:

```
az ad sp list --all --query "[*].[appId]" -o tsv | xargs -I 1 az ad sp credential list --id 1 --query "[].endDate" > end.txt
```

This generates a json array or all the `endDate`s, however it does not save the `appId` that corresponds to the `endDate` and for service principals that do not have any credentials an error message like this is printed in the terminal:

```
ERROR: Can't find associated application id from '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

There are 2 things I would like to solve.
1: To avoid the `ERROR` messages described above by only getting the `appId`s that have `oauth2Permissions`. I've tried adding an `any()` filter to achieve this:

```
az ad sp list --all --filter "oauth2permissions/any()" --query "[*].[appId]" -o tsv | xargs -I 1 az ad sp credential list --id 1 --query "[].endDate" > end.txt
```

But this and other variations I've tried all cause errors or state `Collection open properties are not supported in this release.` What is the correct/best way of doing this?

2: To make use of the output end dates I would like the endDate to be accompanied by some information about the SP, at least the `appId`. So rather than just having a list element like `["2021-05-27T15:39:26.667907+00:00"]` I would like the elements to be dictionaries similar to:

```
[
  {
    "appId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    "endDate": "2021-05-27T15:39:26.667907+00:00"
  }
]
```

This would be simple if the credential itself had the `appId` field but it does not. How can I add information to the output?

Alternatively to addressing these 2 issues separately, is there a different tool/solution that will provide a similar final output in a single command?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recently released some PS scripts that can assist in finding expired creds/certs. Link as follows: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/app-management-powershell-samples

Answer (score 1):

> I recently had an issue that turned out to be caused by an expired service principal credential.

I had a similar problem a few days ago and solved it in a different way, but very similar to the solution you was trying to achieve (I think).

To fix the two issues you described, I ended up with this (not the most elegant, but has been working fine):

```bash
az ad sp list --all --output tsv \
  --query "[? publisherName=='<COMPANY_DOMAIN>' && oauth2Permissions[0]!=null].[appId]" \
  | xargs -I 1 bash -c "eval az ad sp credential list \
    --id 1 --output json --query "[].\{endDate:endDate\}" \
    | jq '. | select(. | . != []) | .[] += {\"appId\": \"1\"}'"
```

1. The `[? publisherName=='<COMPANY_DOMAIN>' && oauth2Permissions[0]!=null]` should workaround those `can't find associated application id` and `collection open properties are not supported in this release` errors.
2. The `+= {\"appId\": \"1\"}` will append the `appId` to the list, replacing that `1` (from xargs) with the correct value.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting. But my `az ad sp list --all` results do not have any mention of either `publisherName` or `oauth2Permissions` so adding that query just gives an empty input to the xargs command.